# Coloring the circles in my graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

I want to make a circle with a white color and black boundary. What should I do?
Here is my code:

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{multicol,multirow}
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage{pgf}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows,automata}
    \usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amscd}
    \usepackage[all]{xy}
    \usepackage{breqn}
    \usepackage{shapepar}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \usepackage{paralist}
    \usepackage{rotating}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \usepackage{subfigure}
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{bidipoem}
    \usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
    \usetikzlibrary[mindmap]
    \usepackage{makeidx}
    \makeindex
    \newcommand{\latex}{\LaTeX\ }
    \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}
    \newtheorem{Def}{Definition}
    \newtheorem{exmp}{Example}
    \newcommand*{\titr}[2]{{\LARGE \bf #1}{\large \bf #2}}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
        \begin{center}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white,minimum size=4.5cm]
                node[concept] {\Large\textsc{Happy}\\[0.1cm]\titr{N}{OW}\titr{R}{UZ}\\[0.3cm]\huge1396}
                child [grow=35,concept color=red,minimum size=3cm] {node[concept]{\large\textbf{\textit{Mental $\&$\\[0cm] Physical\\[0.1cm] Health}}}}
                child [grow=-25,concept color=blue!90,minimum size=2.5cm] {node[concept]{\large\textbf{\textit{Global\\[0.1cm]Peace}}}}
                child [grow=-90,concept color=orange,minimum size=2cm] {node[concept]{\large\textbf{\textit{Too \\[0.1cm]Much \\[0.2cm]Wealth}}}}
                child [grow=-150,concept color=yellow,text=black,minimum size=2.5cm] {node[concept]{\large\textbf{\textit{Full of\\[0.1cm]Happiness}}}}
                child [grow=155,concept color=RubineRed,minimum size=2cm] {node[concept]{\large\textbf{\textit{LOVE}}}}
                child [grow=100,concept color=white,minimum size=2cm,text=black] {node[concept]{\large\textbf{\textit{Warmest\\[0.1cm] Wishes}}}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
    \end{figure}
    \centering \Large
    \sc Sincerely yours,\\
    \sc Ehsan Benabbas
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I think, your WE is not minimal.  You could delete a lot of unconcerned packages.  Did you cut&paste that code from another example?  It ssems, as if you have missed an important style declaration.

Comment: It's my code, I use this packages for all of my latex files so I just copied them. my problem is to color up a circle(a child) with white color and black border.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `draw=black` to the options of the corresponding concept node:

```
node[concept,draw=black]{\large\textbf{\textit{Warmest\\[0.1cm] Wishes}}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\newcommand*{\titr}[2]{{\LARGE \bfseries #1}{\large \bfseries #2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white,minimum size=4.5cm]
    node[concept] {\Large\textsc{Happy}\\[0.1cm]\titr{N}{OW}\titr{R}{UZ}\\[0.3cm]\huge1396}
      child [grow=35,concept color=red,minimum size=3cm] {node[concept]{\large\textbf{\textit{Mental $\&$\\[0cm] Physical\\[0.1cm] Health}}}}
      child [grow=-25,concept color=blue!90,minimum size=2.5cm] {node[concept]{\large\textbf{\textit{Global\\[0.1cm]Peace}}}}
      child [grow=-90,concept color=orange,minimum size=2cm] {node[concept]{\large\textbf{\textit{Too \\[0.1cm]Much \\[0.2cm]Wealth}}}}
      child [grow=-150,concept color=yellow,text=black,minimum size=2.5cm] {node[concept]{\large\textbf{\textit{Full of\\[0.1cm]Happiness}}}}
      child [grow=155,concept color=RubineRed,minimum size=2cm] {node[concept]{\large\textbf{\textit{LOVE}}}}
      child [grow=100,concept color=white,minimum size=2cm,text=black] {node[concept,draw=black]{\large\textbf{\textit{Warmest\\[0.1cm] Wishes}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Draw the concept node twice, once with a thick black border and the second time as it is now. The first node will be completely covered except for the black border.

```
node[concept,draw=black,line width=3pt]{\large\textbf{\textit{Warmest\\[0.1cm] Wishes}}}
node[concept]{\large\textbf{\textit{Warmest\\[0.1cm] Wishes}}}
```

The point of repeating the contents is to let the first covered node have exactly the same size as the second one. Do a few experiments with the line width (here 3pt) until it looks adequate.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap}
\newcommand*{\titr}[2]{{\LARGE \bfseries #1}{\large \bfseries #2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \path[mindmap,concept color=black,text=white,minimum size=4.5cm]
    node[concept] {\Large\textsc{Happy}\\[0.1cm]\titr{N}{OW}\titr{R}{UZ}\\[0.3cm]\huge1396}
      child [grow=35,concept color=red,minimum size=3cm] {node[concept]{\large\textbf{\textit{Mental $\&$\\[0cm] Physical\\[0.1cm] Health}}}}
      child [grow=-25,concept color=blue!90,minimum size=2.5cm] {node[concept]{\large\textbf{\textit{Global\\[0.1cm]Peace}}}}
      child [grow=-90,concept color=orange,minimum size=2cm] {node[concept]{\large\textbf{\textit{Too \\[0.1cm]Much \\[0.2cm]Wealth}}}}
      child [grow=-150,concept color=yellow,text=black,minimum size=2.5cm] {node[concept]{\large\textbf{\textit{Full of\\[0.1cm]Happiness}}}}
      child [grow=155,concept color=RubineRed,minimum size=2cm] {node[concept]{\large\textbf{\textit{LOVE}}}}
      child [grow=100,concept color=white,minimum size=2cm,text=black] {node[concept,draw=black,line width=3pt]{\large\textbf{\textit{Warmest\\[0.1cm] Wishes}}}
   node[concept]{\large\textbf{\textit{Warmest\\[0.1cm] Wishes}}}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```